# add outer border into UItableview cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to outer border shadow like this . Do you have any idea how I can achieve this one . 
I have load all the cell successfully . There are three cells . Look at the picture 
[image]
Here date to total hour one cell

, description is another cell and

supervisor is another cell.

Just tell me how to add only outer border with shadow combinedly all cell .

Comment: Why three different cells and not a single one prototype with all the labels?

Comment: @Kerberos because description and supervisor are dynamic , could more than one